# Hibernate Search - Unknown Service Requested

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, hibernate-search

I'm trying to make use of Hibernate Search in my Java EE 6 project, deployed under JBoss EAP 6.1.  However, I am not seeing the indices being created when I save an object to the database.  The data models are annotated properly with the necessary Hibernate Search annotations.  I've tried to recreate the search indices manually, but when I do I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.search.spi.MassIndexerFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.requestService(FullTextSessionImpl.java:213) [hibernate-search-orm-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.createIndexer(FullTextSessionImpl.java:208) [hibernate-search-orm-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.jpa.impl.FullTextEntityManagerImpl.createIndexer(FullTextEntityManagerImpl.java:292) [hibernate-search-orm-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    at net.odyssi.projectx.web.actions.test.TestAction.reindexData(TestAction.java:564) [classes:]
    at net.odyssi.projectx.web.actions.test.TestAction$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.reindexData(TestAction$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:85) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:112) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:88) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:55) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at net.odyssi.projectx.web.actions.test.TestAction$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.reindexData(TestAction$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 32 more
```

My persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="ProjectX" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ProjectXDatasource</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
                value="java:/ProjectXEntityManagerFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
                value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5" />

            <!-- Caching support -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics"
                value="true" />

            <!-- Hibernate Search properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                value="org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/Volumes/Untitled/workspace/pxindex" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                value="filesystem" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.infinispan.chunk_size"
                value="300000000" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.reader.strategy" value="shared" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.worker.execution" value="sync" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.jmx_enabled" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Hibernate Search, itself, is deployed as a JBoss EAP 6.1 module.  I downloaded the JBoss Modeshape distribution, which includes the Hibernate Search module definitions.  My jboss-deployment-structure.xml file looks like this:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" export="true" />
            <module name="javax.faces.api" export="true" />
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true" />
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" export="true" />

            <module name="org.hibernate" export="true" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" export="true" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.envers" export="true" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" export="true" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.search.engine" services="import"
                export="true" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.search.orm" services="import"
                slot="main" export="true" />

            <module name="org.apache.commons.codec" export="true" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.configuration" export="true" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.io" export="true" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" export="true" />

            <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true" />

            <module name="org.dom4j" export="true" />
            <module name="org.infinispan" export="true" />

            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" export="true" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider"
                export="true" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I do not receive any errors during deployment, and my entities are persisted without any errors.  I just don't see the indices being created, and I get an exception when I try to create them manually.  Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, the ModeShape team made these modules initially, but they later donated them back to the Search project which is now maintaining them. So could you try the modules released by the Hibernate Search team? http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-search/4.4.2.Final/hibernate-search-modules-4.4.2.Final-jbossas-72-dist.zip/download

Comment: I'll give those a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sanne Okay, I've replaced the previous modules with the ones you referenced.  Now, when I try to rebuild the search index I get the following exception:  "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Search Event listeners not configured, please check the reference documentation and the application's hibernate.cfg.xml".  I haven't changed my jboss-deployment-structure.xml, and the module definition appears correct, so I'm not quite sure why it's not being picked up.  I've even tried manually specifying the event listeners in my persistence.xml, but then I get ClassNotFound exceptions

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong in that configuration, I'm not familiar with the modules yet, but this configuration is being tested by our continuous integration: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-deploy-on-AS7.

Comment: BTW if you're using EAP it comes with full support included for Hibernate Search ;-) Might be simpler, support staff is great.